# Access child class fields in a method called by the parent class constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I've defined this class in an application running on Node 12.x.x:

```js
class Parent {
  parentField = "i am a parent field";

  constructor() {
    this.loop();
  }

  loop() {
    for (var field in this) {
      console.log(field);
    }
  }
}
```

...and I've defined another class that inherits from `Parent`:

```js
class Child extends Parent {
  childField = "i am a child field";
}
```

As is, instantiating a `Child` will only log:

```
i am a parent field
```

If I modify `Child` to:

```js
class Child extends Parent {
  childField = "i am a child field";

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.loop();
  }
}
```

...it will now log the child fields too:

```
i am a parent field
i am a parent field
i am a child field
```

According to the spec, fields are only added to `this` after `super()` is called, but this scenario feels very odd from an inheritance perspective. In a situation like this, the child constructor feels superfluous -- it is basically doing the same thing the parent constructor is already doing.

Is there a way to avoid unnecessarily adding a constructor to a child class which is only meant to manually call the same function already being called in the parent class's constructor?

Comment: I don't understand what's "odd from an inheritance perspective". During construction, the parent object constructor should have no knowledge of the child object. Other languages behave similarly. Are you arguing that a parent object's constructor's behavior should vary depending on the child object?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I meant that it's odd when comparing against class-based inheritance in other languages. For instance, the same example in Python would work without the need to override the constructor in the child class. Granted, JavaScript is using prototypical inheritance, so differences are to be expected. But the sugar recently added to JavaScript (especially with fields) makes it misleading -- it's only natural to have expectations based on the similar syntax of other languages.

Comment: Fair enough. I can't speak for the Python case, I was thinking more of how Java/C# behave. But you're right. Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid unnecessarily adding a constructor to a child class which is only meant to manually call the same function already being called in the parent class's constructor?

Only if the function can be called asynchronously (though this is odd):

```js
class Parent {
  parentField = "i am a parent field";

  constructor() {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      this.loop();
    });
  }

  loop() {
    for (var field in this) {
      console.log(field);
    }
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  childField = "i am a child field";
}

const c = new Child();
```

But keep in mind that *you already effectively have constructors* for both classes. De-sugared, a class field is just an assignment to the instance inside the constructor. Your original code:

```
class Child extends Parent {
  childField = "i am a child field";
}
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.childField = "i am a child field";
  }
}
```

As you've seen, since the super's constructor runs before the property assignment occurs, for a synchronous call of `loop`, you have to call `this.loop` inside the child class.

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.childField = "i am a child field";
    this.loop(); // added this line
  }
}
```

It might seem verbose, but it's a perfectly reasonable solution. It's not creating anything unnecessary, it's *only* adding the manual call of `this.loop` at the end of the constructor, which is required.

If you want to avoid calling `this.loop` twice in case the instance is from a subclass rather than the parent, you can check if `this` has a prototype of the `Parent` or not:

```js
class Parent {
  parentField = "i am a parent field";

  constructor() {
    if (this.prototype === Parent) {
      this.loop();
    }
  }

  loop() {
    for (var field in this) {
      console.log(field);
    }
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.childField = "i am a child field";
    this.loop();
  }
}
const c = new Child();
```

Comment: Yeah, it's the sugar that's tripping me up here. De-sugared, the code is reasonable. But when looking at only the sugared code, the requirement of the child constructor feels duplicative. I suppose that's the catch with a language adding sugar though -- it masks what is actually happening and then sometimes results in code that can appear odd. Thanks for the write up!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what potential issues do you see in using the promise-based approach in your first snippet?

Comment: It depends if immediate side-effects *outside* of the class are required which depend on the function. If this is the case, it's usually a reflection of bad design. Eg if the function adds a property to an HTMLElement and then the consumer of the class wants to immediately access that property on the element. That's pretty weird.

Comment: When there are *not* side-effects, the asynchronous method should work. If a consumer of the class calls a method that requires data that is populated by the async method, and the async method hasn't run yet, just run it and return the data. (set a flag so it doesn't run twice in the `Promise.resolve()`)